# How to Map List Values to String using Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

This is my Dto Model Object

```
public class SourceClass
{
    public List<SourceList> SourceLists { get; set; }
}

public class SourceList
{
    public bool Type1 { get; set; }
    public bool Type2 { get; set; }
    public bool Type3 { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

I am mapping to my ViewModel

```
public class DestinationClass
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }

}
```

Using my own Resolver Method. 
The aim is to Map the values to the List to ViewModel Values if the Dto List has corresponding bool as true.

For example,
If the list contain has IsValue1 as true, then the viewModel Value1 need to be updated with the Value coming from IsValue1.

It currently is updating values of all the properties in the viewModel with the same value i.e. Value1, Value2 and Value3 has the same value of value1. As it looks for the condition IsValue1 which is true in the dto unless I remove the value.

```
public class Resolver : ValueResolver<SourceClass, string>
{
    protected override string ResolveCore(SourceClass source)
    {
        if (source.SourceLists.Any())
        {
            foreach (var sourceList in source.SourceLists)
            {
                //if the source list Type1 is true, add the value of the list to the value1
                if (sourceList.Type1.Equals(true))
                {
                    var value1 = sourceList.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    return value1;
                }

                if (sourceList.Type2.Equals(true))
                {
                    var value1 = sourceList.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    return value1;
                }

                if (sourceList.Type3.Equals(true))
                {
                    var value1 = sourceList.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    return value1;
                }
            }
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

The implementation of the code is in this way:

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
  .ForMember(m => m.Value1, o => o.ResolveUsing<Resolver>())
  .ForMember(m => m.Value2, o => o.ResolveUsing<Resolver>())
  .ForMember(m => m.Value3, o => o.ResolveUsing<Resolver>());
```

I could change the code and use individual mapper to correct this however this will in turn defeat the aim of using Automapper.

Comment: You have the same if statement three times:
if (sourceList.Type1.Equals(true))
Shouldn't one be Type1, one Type2 and one Type3?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment I have edited that change in the code. It was a human mistake in copying the codes.

Comment: As a comment, you can clean up your code a bit through things like this:
if (sourceList.Type2)
and
return sourceList.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
The resolver isn't working because you are passing in an array of values and performing the same action on them for each member resolver. There is nothing in your resolver that says you are trying to match Value1/2/3. It is operating on the same array every time and giving the same answer every time. If you want to do it this way, you would need 3 resolvers. ResolverValue1, ResolverValue2, ResolverValue3(or something like that).

Comment: @peinearydevelopment yes. I could do that however I was keeping that as a last resort. I pointed that at the end of my question. I was just trying to write the solution in a bit elegant manner rather than creating individual mapping.
I have managed to resolve this issue however by using the Remove functionality. I will post my answer. However, if anyone has better idea do comment on. I am trying to learn the full potential of Automapper.

Comment: Why is my question down voted?

Answer (score 0):

The way I have resolved this problem is removing the value everytime the condition is satisfied. I have used the RemoveAt function to do it.

My solution

```
  public class Resolver : ValueResolver<SourceClass, string>
   {
    protected override string ResolveCore(SourceClass source)
    {
        var dc = new DestinationClass();
        if (source.SourceLists.Any())
        {
            foreach (var sourceList in source.SourceLists)
            {
                //if the source list Type1 is true, add the value of the list to the value1
                if (sourceList.Type1.Equals(true))
                {
                    dc.Value1 = sourceList.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    source.SourceLists.RemoveAt(0);
                    return dc.Value1;
                }

                if (sourceList.Type2.Equals(true))
                {
                    dc.Value2 = sourceList.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    source.SourceLists.RemoveAt(0);
                    return dc.Value2;
                }

                if (sourceList.Type3.Equals(true))
                {
                    dc.Value3 = sourceList.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    source.SourceLists.RemoveAt(0);
                    return dc.Value3;
                }
            }
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```